# Android SimpleCursorAdapter Problem

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I wrote this method in My DataBaseHelper class:

```
public Cursor fetchData(String tableName) {
    return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT rowid as _id, title FROM "+tableName, null);
}
```

And wrote this code inside one of my activities:

```
    try {
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchData("tableName");
        String[] columns = {cursor.getColumnName(0), cursor.getColumnName(1)}; 
        int[] columnsLayouts = {R.id.layout1, R.id.layout2}; 
        SimpleCursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                            (this.getBaseContext(),
                            android.R.id.list, cursor,columns , columnsLayouts);
        lv.setAdapter(ca); //lv is my ListView with id="@android:id/list"
        txt.setText("Done ! : "); //Process is Ok

    } catch (Exception e){
        txt.setText("Error"); //Error happens
    }
```

The code is compiling ok. However, it closed forcefully when reaching this line `lv.setAdapter(ca);`.

**Is there a problem?
did I do it the wrong way?**

-

UPDATE:
this is the logCat errors (After I filter them by: `android.view`)

[image: LogCat screen]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error! the application force the close. I believe the error is in the `lv.setAdapter()` line but I do NOT know why!

Comment: In case this might help: I declared the view like this: `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: what is the error that is being displayed in your logcat?

Comment: are you extending ListActivity? if yes, just retrieve the ListView using getListView()

Comment: I got many lines in the logCat. They are so much and I could not read and understand them. Your tip about retrieving the view is good. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with the screen shoot. give it a look plz.

Comment: LogCat should tell you the exact line on your code thats generating the error. Also, replace this.getBaseContext() with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android crashes when trying to inflate the items in your list view. The second parameter of the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is layout -

> layout - resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"

You are passing android.R.id.list which sounds to me like you are passing the list id instead of item's id.

Comment: You are TOTALLY right. I forgot about the items layout. Although I have a problem with the SCA, but the force close issue is solved now. Thanks :)